# Segmented Button OpenUI5 setSelectedButton

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to use the function `setSelectedButton()` from [SegmentedButton,](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SegmentedButton.html#setSelectedButton) but i am not able to change the Button.
For Example:

```
var navCheck = new sap.m.SegmentedButton({
    items: [
        new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem("Off", {text: "Navigation Off"}), 
        new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem("On", {text: "Navigation On"})
    ],
    select: function () {
    }
});
```

When I am using `setSelectedButton("On");` the SegmentedButton Element stops selecting any of the Items.

Check this [JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/giyexokupa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have learned so far, `sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem` control has property `oButton` which holds actual id of the button (your ids "on" and "Off" get the "parent" control, not the button itself).

Here how I solved the problem:

```js
doSomething: function() {
    var test = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Test");
    var oButton = sap.ui.getCore().byId("On");
    test.setSelectedButton(oButton.oButton.getId());
}
```

Here is JSBIN example: [LINK](http://jsbin.com/zikuvasego/2/edit?html,output)

If somebody has a better solution, I'd gladly take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setSelectedButton passing in the ID but you need to verify you are using the full ID including any parent aggregation ID's...

The easiest way to is to use the new UI5 chrome inspector and select your button to see the whole ID of the buttons. Then in your code make sure your building the ID's with proper pre-pended aggregation ID's.

Derek

Comment: Applications should **not** rely on global IDs, let alone the automatically generated ones, found in the DOM nodes as they can differ each time depending on which environment the app was launched. E.g. control IDs on FLP have different prefixes compared to standalone apps.